# How to filter even and odd elements?

Tags: go, hugo, go-templates

`{{ if eq ($key % 2) 0 }}`  gives: *unexpected "%" in operand*

`{{ if $key % 2 == 0 }}` gives:  unexpected "%" in operand

### So how do I find even and odd keys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle a boolean variable to detect odd and even elements in a range.

```
 {{- $odd := false}}
 {{range .}}
    {{$odd = not $odd}}
    {{if $odd}}odd:  {{else}}even: {{end}}{{.}}
 {{end}}
```

[Run an example on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/mw-rXgP0MxY).

The first iteration is considered to be odd. Initialize with `$odd := true` to make the first iteration even.

This approach works with Go templates in any context (not just Hugo). This approach also works when ranging over a map.

Answer (score 2):

### Hugo has Math functions

First find reminder than check it in a if clause
Modulus of two integers can be find with  `mod $number 2`

```go
        {{- $reminder := mod $key  2 }}
        {{ if eq $reminder  0 }}
          <p >{{- $value.name -}}</p>
        {{ else }}
          <p>{{- $value.name -}}</p>
        {{ end }}
```